# how Spring MVC find its handler mapping

Tags: spring

in Spring MVC we can configure handler mapping as bean.but how spring examine what is the handler mapping we mentioned in xml?
 simpliy

```
<bean id="simplehandler" class="" />
```

do we need to specify "simplehandler" bean id to somewhere for spring to identify bean handler?

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing that must be clear is that: Spring has several handler mappings.
   And the "*DefaulAnnotationHandlerMapping*" is activated by default (See *DispatcherServlet.properties* in the Spring distribution or just google for it. All default handlers are listed there). Spring will choose "*DefaulAnnotationHandlerMapping*" by default.
2. If you want Spring to use another handler mapping strategy, you have to tell him explicitly

e.g.:

```
<bean  class="org.blablabla......ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
```

Note that this cancels the use of the default handler mapping strategy

3. You can also tell Spring to use several handler mapping strategy and prioritized them by using the *order* property in the mappers declaration

something like

```
<bean class="org.blabla....DefaulAnnotationHandlerMapping" >
<property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
<bean  class="org.blablabla......ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
<property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Hope this helps. And sorry if the syntax of my bean declaration is not 100% correct. I had to write quickly ;-)